# How to enable openssl support in XAMPP?

Tags: openssl, xampp

I am trying to enable openssl support in XAMPP.  I am followed these instructions, but got an error:

```
1.  Open php.ini and  uncomment the following:  extension=php_openssl.dll

2.  Make sure you have config the following section pointing to your 
php install directory (in my case is located in a second partition at 
e:\php)

3.  Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "e:/php/ext"

4.  Add your php directory to the PATH variable
start>run>type cmd
on windows console type:
set PATH=%PATH%;e:\php
(remember replace e:\php with YOUR directory)
(note that using %path% is the same as var+=value, so the directory 
will be appended at the end of the variable)

5.  php5 comes with all the dll in the zip package so if you add the php 
directory to the path variable, you don't need to move anything to your 
windows system directory (very safe for later updates, because you just 
replace the content of your php directory)

6.  start>run>inetsrv/iis.msc
right click on your computer
all task>restart IIS
```

When I look up `phpinfo()` it says openssl support is enabled.

But when I try to run the command line I get an error:

```
openssl.cnf not found.
```

What does this error mean and what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get openssl, curl and intl enabled on your xampp server follow the following steps below:

NB: the above steps are ok but you wont get nowhere if you are a newbie in code editing

1. open the location where your xampp server is installed e.g `C:\xampp or C:\program files\xampp` depending on where yours is installed
2. search for the search bar in the folder where your xampp server is installed
3. type `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` or `C:\program files\xampp\php\php.ini` , then open the php.ini file using either notepad or wordpad
4. then scroll until you see `;extension=openssl.dll, ;extension=curl.dll, ;extension=intl.dll`, then remove the comment (;) and save your file
5. shutdown your server by quitting and restart it

Comment: Tried this but not working for me, still getting from composer:
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.